# Is there a way to track a rectangle on a JPanel (Like 3rd person)?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, game-physics

I've made a few 2D games using JPanels and the Graphics draw methods. For the game I'm currently working on, I'd like to be able track the player as they walk, from an aerial view (sort of like the earlier Pokemon games, where as you move the camera tracks you), but without having to hard code it (make it that when I walk, the x and y values of every other feature including the background moves the opposite direction). Is there another way to do this or will I have to hard code it?

Comment: *"Is there another way to do this.."* Use an `AffineTransform`

Comment: @LuxxMiner Thank you for the link, I'm going to have a closer look to see how I can implement that. All that I meant by hard code was code it that when I moved up, every other object on the panel moves down, to create the appearance of being tracked. (Basically make it that you don't actually move, everything around you moves to create the illusion of movement :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Graphics.translate(x,y)` where x and y positions are the positions of your camera or player. This will translate the origin of the graphics context to the point x, y.

Comment: Ah yes, this would work perfectly if I re-scaled the image :), it would also mean I don't have to touch any values besides the player's and the Graphics. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MorganBlem Note that for (x,y) that is assuming your Camera coord's are negative, (which is the standard practice, it makes rotation and other things much easier in the future). Just a heads up.

Comment: @MitchWeaver what is assuming x and y is negative?

Comment: @MorganBlem If you have a camera class the best practice is set your camera positions equals to negative player positions.When you move right the world should "move" left. Think about it. :)  If you dont have seperated camera class you can just pass negative player positions to translate.

Comment: Oh yes I knew that :) thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @eldo I've run into a bit of a problem.. I got this to work, and got it to track my ship around, BUT, it messes up my targeting system completely. at first I didn't understand why, since the system uses only x and y values of a mouseclick, then I realized this: while the graphics is being translated, the x and y co ordinates of the mouseclick stay the same relative the to the panel, they don't get the translated co ordinates.. Can I fix any easy way or will I have to apply the translation to mouselisteners as well..?

Comment: @MorganBlem I see. Without seeing your code i'd say translating back to the original position would solve your problem. Edit your render method by adding translate(-x,-y) after you finished rendering. The negative value of whatever you passed to translate first.

Comment: @MorganBlem And MouseEvent class also has a translate method i have never tried: translatePoint(int x, int y) "Translates the event's coordinates to a new position by adding specified x (horizontal) and y (vertical) offsets." It could also work but i suggest the first one if that works.

Comment: @eldo I think in this situation the mouse translate would've helped but I just set it that when I move with the keys the target moves by the same amount, which ixed it :)